# What TV show is playing in the first episode of Ms. Marvel?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022

In the first episode, Kamala Khan gets home and lies on a sofa and watches the TV only to be interrupted by her mother's complaining about the material she is seeing. The image was flipped upside down but it probably showed something not *conservative* enough to trigger her mother's reaction. Any idea what was that TV show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She's watching [*Felicity*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134247/), specifically it would appear to be the season 1 finale "Felicity Was Here".

[image: First image shows the TV upside down, then Kamala on her bed upside down and laslty, the TV again with the subtitles "What are you watching? Turn that off!"]

<sub>*Information found from [BuzzFeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/noradominick/ms-marvel-episode-1-easter-eggs-details).*</sub>

Comment: Fitting for it to be show that—totally out of the blue—turned out to feature time travel.